# OneToMany not populated in view but populated if loaded by Controller

Tags: one-to-many, playframework-2.0

I am starting to learn Play Framework 2, and have met a strange problem.

I have a `OneToMany` relationship defined between a `Project` and its many `Task`s.

```
@Entity
public class Project extends Model {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="project", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
}

@Entity
public class Task extends Model {
    @ManyToOne
    public Project project;
}
```

I have some code that finds and displays a `Project` :

```
final Project foundProject = Project.find(id);
//Logger.error("Tasks size:"+foundProject.tasks.size());
return ok(views.html.tasks.render(foundProject, taskForm));
```

And a view:

```
@for(task <- project.tasks) {
    <li>@task.title</li>
}
```

Note the commented-out `Logger` line in the code that finds the `Project`. If that line is commented out, then no `Task`s are shown, if the line is NOT commented out, then `Task`s are shown.

It's as if some kind of lazy initialisation code works inside the Controller but not inside the View. Is there a subtlety of Play that I have missed, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my fault - I'm new to eBean and was doing this in the code to find my project:

```
finder.ref(id);
```

instead of:

```
finder.byId(id);
```